# Windows 10 explorer does not detect Inateck SSD drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, ssd, data-recovery

Last week, I spilled some coffee on my laptop. It was unrecoverable. So, I extracted the 256 GB SSD drive and mounted it on a Inateck Sata m.2 external box with USB cable.

My new laptop is on Windows 10 and the device manager detects the Inateck (ASMT 2115 USB device), but windows explorer does not show the content of my SSD.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you look in disk management ? Can you see it there?

Comment: First of all, make sure it is compatible. Inateck FE2012N, for instance, *supports M.2 port of SATA protocol (not support PCI - E or NVMe protocols)*.

Comment: @Moab: I see Disk 1 Removable E: 'No media'

Comment: @JVerstry That either means exactly what I commented above, i.e., not compatible *or* that the SSD is gone.

Comment: I would try another sata to usb device just to be sure it is not the issue, but does sound like the drive is dead,

Answer (score 0):

Dismantled the Inateck and moved the m.2 SSD a little in its slot. After some time, Windows 10 would detect it. Apparently, it is a connection issue.

Comment: The SATA to usb device is crappy... works, doesn't work...